# asset_sync and aws beanstalk asset pipeline manifest not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asset-sync

Asset Sync is working and the assets are saved to the s3 bucket.

```
GET http://s3.amazonaws.com/app-staging/javascripts/application.js 404 (Not Found)
```

It shouldn't be `/javascripts/application.js` it should be `/assets/application.js`!

The app is deployed on AWS Beanstalk. I have a feeling the manifest file did not get saved. How would I check? Where can I see the public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, worked the second-time around with no changes. Weird.